# Are there examples showing the use of protocol buffers (protobuf) messages as entities in GC Datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, protocol-buffers

I'd like to use Datastore to hold objects created as protocol buffers.  The definitions of these message payloads are in a .proto file and my service will receive them in an incoming API call.  There are nested 'entities' within.

I know that Datastore can use these: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#embedded_entity

Can anyone point me to example code?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any standard facility for converting a valid arbitrary protocol buffer into a valid Cloud Datastore entity. While entities are roughly analogous in structure to protocol buffers, they don't have the exact same support.

You'd have to write a custom translation layer yourself, taking into consideration the requirements specific to the protocol buffers you're working with.

Comment: So the docs referenced above allow you to do what, exactly?  Store it as a blob?

Comment: The docs are more talking about what the proto or JSON message we send you for these data types look like - not how to store proto or JSON messages in these data types.

Comment: Oh I really had it wrong.  Thanks for straightening me out.

Comment: @DanMcGrath Can Google provide a facility for storing arbitrary protos in Datastore? It seems there is already way to store protocol buffers called [Messages](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/protorpc/messages/messageclass) in Datastore. Messages appear similar (but not drop-in-replacable) to the standard protoc Python codegen of .proto srcs. It looks like https://github.com/google/protorpc is supposed to handle this, but it seems out of step with [the other protobuf codegen solution](https://github.com/google/protobuf).